# Asset pipeline looks in wrong directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I added this line in my layout file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap", "bootstrap-responsive", :cache => true%>
```

Which produces this error message:

> Errno::ENOENT in Test#index
>
> No such file or directory - Asset file not found at '/Developer/Workspace/MyProj/public/stylesheets/Developer/Workspace/MyProj/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css'

It appears to have concatenated the path to the folder twice before looking for the file.  Is this a known issue with rails 3.2.3?  Or is there some setting I mucked up?

Comment: Did you upgrade an old project or started a new 3.2 one?

Comment: It was generated as v3.2, I think.  (This project is only a few months old.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try removing ":cache => true"

> If you take a look at https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6752/files#L0R40 you will see the line, which produces wrong path when cache or concat options are enabled. In this case paths will looks like "/Absolute/path/to/public/" + "/Absolute/path/to/asset/file.ext" which is wrong.

[-- Rails pull request that seems to be related to your issue.](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6834)